# None of the C compilers are Working In code :: blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I was trying to use code::blocks to do some programming and none of the C compilers seem to work so can you recommend me a compiler?

The error I get is:

```
Project/Target: "Email Sender V4 - Debug":
  The compiler's setup (Intel C/C++ Compiler) is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
  Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
  Do you have a compiler installed?
Goto "Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->Intel C/C++ Compiler->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.

Tried to run compiler executable 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Compiler\C++\9.0/bin/icl.exe', but failed!

Run aborted...
```

Comment: `tempmail` and `tempFile` are used without being declared. I don't think no compiler will support your code unless you define them as macro via compilation option.

Comment: _"none of the C compilers seem to work"_: what does that mean exactly? Did you get error messages? Did the program run but not as you expected? Can you compile and run a simple Hello World program?

Comment: "*None of the C compilers are Working In code*", "*can recommend me a compiler for my code*" ... I *think* you are asking the wrong question(s) here. You need help to fix *your* code, there's *probably* nothing wrong with the compilers. You should be specific, and describe what happens when you try to compile, e.g. what errors you get, or what output/undesired behavior you get when you try to run it.

Comment: `return 0:` is also wrong. I don't think this can be recovered via compilation options :(

Comment: yeah im getting errors with the compiler

Comment: If your compilers give you compiler errors for your code then they are working just fine. You can probably fix your problem by reading the error messages carefully. Try a HelloWorld. If your compilers work smoothly with that then the problem is only that the shown code is incorrect, which it definitly is.

Comment: Discussing how to fix the errors mentioned by a perfectly working compiler for the shown code is not answering the question here. The fact that there are compiler errors means the answer is already found, or that the question is off-topic for not being reproducable. @Jabberwocky

Comment: but thanks for debugging my code as well :))))

Comment: SOUNDS MORE LIKE YOU ARE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH YOUR ENVIRONMENT, AND WITH CAPS LOCK.

Comment: i have compiler installed but it gave me this error actually i used another one as well

Answer (score 1):

As the output suggests:

> Do you have a compiler installed?

You may have downloaded Code::Blocks without a compiler.

So you could e.g. reinstall [Code::Blocks bundled with MinGW](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) (probably easiest). See also the [docs](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html).

Alternatively, install a separate compiler. The Intel compiler can e.g. be downloaded from [there](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/free-intel-software-developer-tools.html).

Comment: Or better, just download the Code::Blocks that includes MinGW64 with it `:)`